# can't import module relative to the directory the script is being run on

Tags: python, path, python-import, relative-path

As of until now, my understanding is that python imports module by the path relative to the directory, despite the source file being anywhere else.

for example:

```
bar
 |-foo.py
 |-foo1.py
```

so if we want to access `fo01.py` through
`foo.py` from `bar`, I would think I need to do
`from bar import foo1`. But the former does not seem to work.

It not being the way has this following issue:

if we now have another dir - `examples`

```
bar
 |-foo.py
 |-foo1.py
examples
 |- getfoo.py
```

How can we access `foo` and `foo1` under `bar` from `getfoo.py` under examples? (My common intuition would be, import `foo` from the scope of `bar.<foo>`, but it does not work)

Answer (score 1):

before explaining why and how to make things work.
let me put some right code.

here is the dir tree(which followed yours)

```
.
├── bar
│   ├── foo1.py
│   └── foo.py
└── examples
    └── getfoo.py
```

and there is a variable named `var` in foo1.py and foo.py

Question I:

> so if we want to access fo01.py through foo.py from bar, I would think I need to do from bar import foo1. But the former does not seem to work.

Answer I:

> In `foo.py`. you should change `from bar import foo1` to `from foo1 import xxx` (`xxx` are things you want from `foo1.py`)

Question II:

> How can we access foo and foo1 under bar from getfoo.py under examples? (My common intuition would be, import foo from the scope of bar., but it does not work)

Answer II:

> You can't import modules like this before you add some `sys path`, when you're testing py file like `python getfoo.py`.
> if you want to do things like `from bar import foo`, you may need to `sys.path.append('path/to/bar')`, after which you can do the imports.

Explanations:

these are things about `python interpret path`. which you can find in [python sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20path#sys.path)

when we do `python file.py`, the interpreter creates a list that contains all of directories it will use to search for modules when importing automatically.

you can see the list with `import sys; print(sys.path)`

the problem is that this list only contain the directory where file.py is located and some system path that python own.

So, in `bar` directory, you can access `foo1.py` through foo.py using `from foo1 import xxx`.
or `from foo import xxx` in `foo1.py`

But you can not import bar in `getfoo.py`. this is because python interpreter don't know where to find it.
so if you want to import things tell the interpreter with `sys.path.append('path/to/add')`

Comment: the thing about `python interpret path` is quite interestting. Certainly explains why when the program is being run from any dir, all the locations to the import modules remain findable, thus maintaining its relative paths.

Comment: however when the a <module> has `__init__.py` in it, one needs to specify the fullpath to module from the scope of the module that has `__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try importing foo1.py in getfoo1.py using its path.

```
import ../bar/foo1.py
```

Or
copy paste foo1.py in examples and then call

```
import foo1.py
```

Please check syntax for "import ../bar/foo1.py"